# Android vector width fill parent

Tags: android, xml, vector, width, drawable

I have this drawable vector

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="360dp"
  android:height="48dp"
  android:viewportWidth="360"
  android:viewportHeight="48">

  <path
    android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:pathData="M267,12.5L267,36.5"
    android:strokeWidth="0.5"
    android:strokeColor="#E6E6E6" />

</vector>
```

I want this vector to fill the parent width, however in some devices the width is bigger than 360dp.
I need something like:

```
android:width="100%"
```

or

```
android:width="fill_parent"
```

in the vector tag, however this two examples are not options for the vector attribute **android:width**

Comment: You can not set these 2 values which you added into question. But you have way to do it. VD can fill the view, so set view's width as match_parent.

Comment: Thank you! That helps!